# Eclipse->New Android Projects always compile java 1.4

Tags: java, android, eclipse, java-compiler-api

Everytime I add/create or copy a Project inside my Eclipse-Workspace it will be recognized as a Java 1.4 Project, which leads to a sum of errors. I have to fix this myself under properties->java-compiler and check 1.6 there. So I have a few questions on that:
Is it possible to pre-define which compiler Eclipse has to choose?
Is there a config file telling eclipse which compiler to choose?

Comment: How do you add/create or copy a Project inside your Eclipse-Workspace?

Comment: it appears on all: add create and copie manually. Even if i take Eclipse's import feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check under Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler. There is "Compiler compliance level", it should be set to your desired level. :)

If that does not work, go to the "New Java Project" dialog and pres "Configure JREs". Make sure your desired JRE is selected.

Comment: already set it there to 1.6, but new projects still seem to try 1.4 first.

Comment: basically the same as @Scott stated: Window->Preferences_Installed JRE. This doesn't work! Did I mention that I'm working on Android Projects?

Answer (score 0):

Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler

Comment: this doesn't help, as I selected 1.6 already there. I also tried "workspace-settings"

Comment: Then go to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE and check 1.6.